# How to show the hierarchy with different control in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have a list, just like the one below

- Settings 1

  - Number of item [TextBox]
  - Setting 2

    - Is flag [CheckBox]
- Setting 3
  ........ so on and so forth...

I need to show in hierarchy, based on parent node type, I need to show child with a specific control.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a [TreeView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: No, I am looking for to change control in HierarchicalDataTemplate based on the parent type as I have shown , some time I need checkbox and something text box in different way.

Comment: To do that you would need to use a DataTemplateSelector which is not available nativly in Silverlight but this article shows how to implement that. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector